# promise inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sails.js, bluebird

```js
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  tableName: 'category',
  adapter: 'someMysqlServer',
  migrate: 'safe',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,

  // get child categories by parent_id/category_id 
  getCategories: function(parent_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Category.query("SELECT * FROM category c LEFT JOIN category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) LEFT JOIN category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = " + parent_id + " AND cd.language_id = '1' AND c2s.store_id = '0' AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)", function(error, response) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else {
          resolve(response);
        }
      });
    });
  },

  // get left side category

  getLeftSideCategory: function() {

    var allTopCat = Category.getCategories(0);
    var cat = [];

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Promise.each(allTopCat, function(item, i) {

        var child = Category.getCategories(item.category_id);
        child.then(function(children, error) {
          cat[i].child = children;
          cat[i].item = item;
        });

      });
      resolve(cat);
    });
  }
}
```

In model of sails.js I need to call one method inside a `for` loop. After that, I need to collect the data and make an array. Then I have to send the final array to the controller. But I am getting blank array here and after that I am getting an error `"Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot set property 'child' of undefined  "`. What do I need to change here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor the second function as follows

```
getLeftSideCategory: function() {
  return Category.getCategories(0).reduce(function(finalArray, item){
    return Category.getCategories(item.category_id).then(function(children){
      finalArray.push({child: children, item: item});
      return finalArray;
    });
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other option ? it is dead slow.

Comment: Instead of make one query for every category returned by getGategories(0), I guess you can create an array with the categories id and then query the Category model passing the array as parameter. 
Something like (assuming you are including lodash)

`return Category.getCategories(0).
then(function(aCat){
  var aCatIds = _.pluck(aCat, 'id);
  return Category.findAll(aCatIds)
})`

Comment: But parent categoriesId is also dynamic . It is coming from database. We can't hard code this.

Answer (score 0):

```
getLeftSideCategory: function() {
        var allCategories=[];
  return Category.getCategories(0).reduce(function(finalArray, item){
    return Category.getCategories(item.category_id).then(function(children){

      allCategories.push({child: children, item: item});
      return allCategories;
    });
  }, []);
}
```

we have to edit it like this and it is working now

Comment: Yes, sorry for that :)